# "overflow: hidden;" for percentage sized table cells

Tags: html, css

I want a table filling the whole window, with 2 rows each filling half of the height of the table(as well as the window), and keeping this layout while the window is being resized. I can do it when the contents don't overflow, but when contents in the 1st row desires a height larger than the calculated height by percentage, the row doesn't keep the percentage any more, instead, it stays with the desired height and pushes the 2nd row out of the window. I tried "overflow: hidden;" for rows, but that's not the way it works. How can I do it then?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html,body{height:100%;}
            table{height:100%;}
            table>tbody>tr{height:50%;overflow:hidden;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>abc<br />abc<br />abc<br />abc<br />abc<br />abc<br />abc<br     />abc<br /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>def</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have "height:100%;", but have not "width:100%;". Giving "width:100%;" gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS like below.

```
 html,body{height:100%; padding:0; margin:0;}
 table{height:100%;}
 table td{height:100%; overflow:auto; display:block; border:1px solid #ff00ff;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6qad6946/)

Comment: I want **2 rows each filling half of the height of the window**, but in this demo the 1st row takes most of height.

Comment: did you check it out? I can see the same half height for each row. I am using chrome.

Comment: I checked it out with ie11, and now I checked it again with chrome, yes it meets my request, but as said it behaves differently in ie11..